# How to fix what CCSM does to Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, compiz, unity-2d

I installed CCSM a little while back.  Then I enabled "blur windows" and the desktop got all messed up, Unity 2D still works fine.

I have tried every fix I've found here on Askubuntu but still can't get Unity 3D to work normally. Is there something I'm missing?

I activated "blur windows", by now I already uninstalled it, wiped all config files to it I was able to find and tried `unity --reset` , `unity --replace` and `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1` no success.

Comment: what you changed in ccsm would be most helpful for anyone having a desire to help you

Comment: I activated "blur windows", by now I already uninstalled it, wiped all config files to it I was able to find and tried `unity --reset` and `unity --replace` no success.

Comment: I forgot to mention I did that as well. hmmm... :(

Comment: It seems like disabling that plugin by unchecking the "enable" checkbox should undo anything it would be doing.  Perhaps it's something else that got changed?

Comment: @MartyFried When I enabled it, the desktop immediately got messed up, and upon disabling it all windows became unclickable for a little while, after that no window borders or title bars appeared and it remains like that. also CTRL-ALT-T for calling the terminal stopped working as well. the 2D option really saved me.

Comment: No windows or titlebars sounds to me like the window decorator crashed, or compiz itself crashed.  I would check in CCSM, in the plugin section "Window Decoration", and make sure it is checked, then see what the setting is for "Command".  It normally is `/usr/bin/compiz-decorator`.  If this is all there, I'd try running `compiz --replace` from Alt-F2 (using a terminal will only work until you close the terminal).  You can also run `compiz-decorator --replace`.

Comment: I'm sorry fellas, but none of these solutions ever worked, I'm right now commenting from a clean Ubuntu install. In any case, thanks a LOT for the comments and answers :)

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `.compiz` and `.gconf/apps/compiz` folder from your home directory. Press `CTRL+H` to see hidden files. logout and login again.
  or
- If you have CCSM, go to the preference window by clicking the button in the left-bottom. In the profile page, Click on the **Reset to defaults**. Logout and Login again.

Comment: I'm sorry but none of these solutions ever worked, I'm right now commenting from a clean Ubuntu install. In any case, thanks a LOT for the comments and answers :)